# Convert 64 bit .dll file to 32 bit

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

On internet there are lot of discussion on converting `32 bit` `.dll` file to `64 bit`. But I want reverse of it.

Is there a way to convert `64 bit` compiled `.dll` file to its `32 bit` version?

Comment: of course not possible both variants if you have no src code and can rebuild it

Comment: It's not *impossible* impossible, it's merely practically impossible. Almost every other approach will be easier including tracking down its original authors, licensing the source code from them and recompiling it for 32bit.